# NDK is not configured issue in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

My Application is built successfully on Eclipse but fails to Build on android studio.
It returns the error code Ndk is not Configured.
Then I've added `ndk` path to `build.gradle` then its showing the following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:nano:assembleDebug]
WARNING [Project: :nano] Current NDK support is deprecated.  Alternative will be provided in the future.
:nano:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:nano:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:nano:compileDebugNdk
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:\Users\admin\nano\nano\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/la_audio_processing_android/C_\Users\admin\nano\nano\src\main\jni', needed by `C:\Users\admin\nano\nano\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/la_audio_processing_android/C_\Users\admin\nano\nano\src\main\jni\LA_PostProcessing.o'.  Stop.
Error:Execution failed for task ':nano:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\ndk\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.449 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is the problem faced by Android studio users in Windows environment. 
First for NDK not Configured problem

Go to `local.properties` file and give `ndk` path...
for ex :

```
#Wed Mar 18 14:10:33 IST 2015
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk1
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\ndk
```

Then for the Next Problem or Error...

Goto JNI Folder and create an empty c file by any name...
Then your problem will be solved...

Some Quick links about this are
http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/
And
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66937

Comment: A Linux Mint 17 problem as well.

Comment: my local.properties looks like this on osx (Android Studio) - Flutter Project:

`sdk.dir=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk`
`ndk.dir=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/ndk`

Comment: and this when using older NDK version `ndk.dir=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle`

Answer (score 38):

**Go to option File->Project Structure**

[image]

**Select SDK Location->Android NDK Location and choose NDK listed in dropdown**

[image]

Comment: This resolved my problem on MacOS (Catalina) - thanks!

Comment: well what if android ndk location is greyed and is not available

Comment: It was grayed for me too. I fixed the problem by adding `ndk.dir=/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670` to my `local.properties` file

Comment: For the "no platforms error":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228822/ndk-does-not-contain-any-platforms

Answer (score 15):

For whatever reason, setting `ndk.dir` on the properties file is not working for me. However, setting/exporting the variable `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` prior to launching android studio did the trick.

**Bash syntax (paths below are specific to my installation)**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle
```

**Environment**

```
Ubuntu Linux x64/GNU bash, version 4.4/Android Studio 2.2.3
```

Answer (score 12):

Goto Files -> Project Structure -> SDK Location

Android NDK Location is at the bottom right of the window.

Answer (score 10):

I use Android Studio 1.4.1.

Below is my local.properties

ndk.dir=C:\Users\BestQ\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C:\Users\BestQ\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

It work well.

Answer (score 8):

In `build.gradle` use

```
android {
  ndkVersion '21.1.6352462' 
}
```

and use `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, you need to point exact version of ndk version on the  `local.properties` file like that:

```
ndk.dir=/Users/ali6p/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147
```

If you need to install a specific version of ndk bundle, open Android Studio preferences and install the version (Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools: Show Package Details > NDK (Side by side): check the version:

[image: Android studio preferences to install ndk version]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was caused by the target file not being found (in my case, a git sub-module needed to be checked out), so ensure all the referenced files exist on the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the NDK is not installed.
If it's the case, go to SDK Manager (top-right icon).
Go to Android SDK > SDK Tools
Check NDK (Side by side) and install it.

[image]