# Android NDK configuration: Execution failed for task

Tags: android, android-ndk

Same issue as [NDK is not configured issue in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29122903/ndk-is-not-configured-issue-in-android-studio). I added the path to the properties file and then got the error message. Then I added an empty test.c to the jni folder under app/src/main/jni, as well as app/src/main/jni/jni, but the error is till there.

```html
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Richard Jiang\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I went to the android-ndk-r10e and there is a file called ndk-build.cmd, so I really don't know how to solve the issue.

Comment: If you follow this answer correctly, I am 99% sure, you problem will solve http://stackoverflow.com/a/27481081/1061944

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in your ndk path, I guess that's what make he call to ndk-build.cmd fail. Try to move it somewhere else.

Else you should be able to get a more explicit error from the "Messages" tab from Android Studio.