# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception in Android Studio Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Can anyone explain why I have this error? I tried also downloading NDK but when it finish it says `NDK does not contain any platforms.` Any help is much appreciated thanks in advance.

> This is my Error in my console
> [image]

> I have also error in my build.gradle
> [image]

*Local Properties*

[image]

Comment: Check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228822/ndk-does-not-contain-any-platforms

Answer (score 0):

Can you specifying `ndk` version in `build.gradle` file

```
android {
        ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
    }
```

And inside local.properties remove

```
ndk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
```

line otherwise it may conflicts with path

Comment: thanks for your response do you mean I just need to put this line `ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'` in my build.gradle?

Comment: also I don't have any `ndk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle`  in my local.properties [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHhoo.png)

Comment: Not '21.3.6528147', you need find installed NDK version